# Pandas: Different behavior of merge in pandas version 1.1.5 and 1.2.0

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
 mapping = pd.merge(
        df_1, df_2, how="left", on=["DLM"]
    )
```

The above code executes and does the job done for pandas version 1.1.5 but the code doesn't work for pandas 1.2.0 or above, it doesn't throw any error but even though there will be a joining partner it doesn't join properly

Example

df_1

| A | DLM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

df_2

| DLM | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |

Result of pandas 1.1.5

| A | DLM | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | NaN |

Result of pandas 1.2.0

| A | DLM | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 4 | NaN |

PS : This is not my data exactly and I can't post the data which I am using.

Comment: Are any of `A`, `DLM`, or `B` indexes in either dataframe?

Comment: No , They are not the indexes

Comment: Using the latest version of Pandas 1.5.3 then `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how = 'left', on='DLM')` gives the result you ascribe to 1.1.5.

Comment: also for me both `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how = 'left', on='DLM')` and `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how = 'left', on=['DLM'])` return the results ascribed to 1.1.5

Answer (score 1):

The [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#reshaping) talk about a bug resolved in version 1.2.0.:

> Bug in DataFrame.merge() and pandas.merge() returning inconsistent ordering in result for how=right and how=left (GH35382)

I assume this is what causes the function to work differently in the two versions.